# PHP MD5 different results

Tags: md5

I'm try to get a MD5 value of a string

> test%40abc.com05a671c66aefea124cc08b76ea6d30bb11.250.55.65MAIDAz3yq007svng4pbhwvtg32mgif3llea7i

From different MD5 online convert sites I got different results

In http://www.md5.cz/, it returns:
c4c794a5488a729a715a877111251405

In http://www.adamek.biz/md5-generator.php, it returns:
658451b9193e198190873d0d4f20df21

Do anyone have ideas why they got different results?

Answer (score 2):

The '%' in the string is confusing at least one of the sites. When you remove the '%' sign then both sites give the same MD5 hash. There are no 'salts' added by the websites.

I suspect  that one of the sites may be using the 'urldecode' function on the input string. the results are:

```
string 'Input    : test%40abc.com05a671c66aefea124cc08b76ea6d30bb11.250.55.65MAIDAz3yq007svng4pbhwvtg32mgif3llea7i' (length=102)
string 'urldecode: test@abc.com05a671c66aefea124cc08b76ea6d30bb11.250.55.65MAIDAz3yq007svng4pbhwvtg32mgif3llea7i' (length=104)
```

The website [www.md5.cz](http://www.md5.cz/) returns the same result of: c4c794a5488a729a715a877111251405

for both of the above input strings,

Comment: Yes I do notice it's the problem of the '%', but have no idea why this make the difference

Answer (score 0):

One or both may be using random salts, which are intended to add a unique touch to the outputs of identical inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
@ and %40 has the same value, becouse @ is converted to %40.
Maybe RCF 1738 and RCF3986 diferences cause this problem?

> urlencode function and rawurlencode are mostly based on RFC 1738.
>
> However, since 2005 the current RFC in use for URIs standard is RFC
>   3986.
>
> Here is a function to encode URLs according to RFC 3986.
>
> ```
> <?php
> function myUrlEncode($string) {
>     $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25',
> ```
>
> '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
>           $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", 
>   ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
>           return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
>       }
>       ?>